# Drupal setup one language: locale vs. stringoverrides

Tags: i18n-l10n

I was wondering what would be the best way to build a website which has only one language. In order to make existing strings translatable we can:

1. use the Locale module and add a 'dead' language which we set default and use to translate all our custom strings
2. Use the String Overrides module to translate our custom strings

What should we do with bigger websites?

Comment: Can you clarify? Why can't you use the existing modules for translation? Most strings in Drupal are already translatable or can be made so. If you are only changing a few occurrences of text, use String Overrides, but don't use it for large-scale translation. That isn't its purpose.

Comment: I wanted to start a discussion about when to use stringoverrides and when to use locale module. :) I have made a small website (one language) and was asked myself the question what should be best...

Comment: When you say one language, do you mean the site is monolingual or has one additional language?